# Amount of Possible Bootstrap Samples

Tags: bootstrap, sample, combinatorics

I know that the total possible amount of distinct bootstrap resamples of size $n$ is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$. Is there any way to prove or justify this?

Comment: Proof is by induction. Start with n=2, then show that for any arbitrary dataset, you can create "new" datasets by replacing one or more observations from the existing unique bootstrapped datasets with the new observation, deduplicating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A standard technique is the "stars and bars" construction.**

By "distinct bootstrap resample" what you mean is a sequence of $N$ elements of a set of size $N$ *without paying attention to their order.*  Enumerate this set as $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N\}.$  Corresponding to any such sequence is the unique ordered sequence in which all of the $x_1$ in the bootstrap sample (if any) precede all the $x_2$ in the sample, which precede all the $x_3$ in the sample, *etc.*  This sequence, in turn, is determined by the counts $n_j$ of each $x_j.$

**Draw a diagram of this sequence** by placing $n_1$ stars `*` (representing the $n_1$ copies of $x_1$ in the sample) followed by a bar `|` to their right, then $n_2$ stars (representing the $n_2$ copies of $x_2$ in the sample) followed by another bar, and so on, until placing the last $n_N$ stars (but not followed by any bar).

For instance, in a set of $N=5$ elements suppose the bootstrap sample is $(x_1,x_5,x_3,x_4,x_3).$  Its ordered version is $(x_1,x_3,x_3,x_4,x_5),$ for which the counts are $(n_i) = (1,0,2,1,1).$  Its stars-and-bars diagram therefore is

> `* | | * * | * | *`

Clearly such a diagram always has $N$ stars (because the bootstrap sample has $N$ elements) and $N-1$ bars (because they separate $N$ groups of stars).  Numbering the $N+N-1$ symbols left to right as $1,2,\ldots, 2N-1,$ note that the bars in this example have the numbers $\{2,3,6,8\}\subset\{1,2,\ldots,9\}.$

Conversely, corresponding to any diagram of $N$ stars and $N-1$ bars and an enumeration of $N$ observations we can recover the bootstrap sample.  *E.g.*, the diagram

> `| | | * * * | | * * | * * * |`

with $N=8$ stars and $7$ bars corresponds to the (sorted) bootstrap sample $(x_4,x_4,x_4,\,x_6,x_6,\,x_7,x_7,x_7)$ of an eight-element set.  The bars appear at positions $\{1,2,3,7,8,11,15\}\subset\{1,2,\ldots,15\}.$

**To count the distinct bootstrap samples, then, it suffices to count the distinct stars and bars diagrams.**  But each such diagram corresponds to an $N-1$-element subset of $N+N-1=2N-1$ positions: namely, the positions in which the bars are located.  By definition, this count is the binomial coefficient $\binom{2N-1}{N-1},$ *QED.*

---

#### Application

There are very efficient methods to sample without replacement and to return that result in order.  **Thus, you can create bootstrap samples very efficiently with stars and bars.**

**To illustrate,** here is an `R` implementation.  Given a dataset `x`, it generates an array, `samples`, whose columns represent all possible bootstrap resamples of `x` in terms of the positions of the bars.  (This makes it impractical to apply to real problems, where $\binom{2N-1}{N-1}$ is so large that `samples` cannot be stored or even computed in reasonable time.)  Because the relative chance of a resample with counts $(n_i)$ is $1/\prod (n_i!),$ columns cannot be selected uniformly from this array: the draws must be weighted by these relative chances.  A caller-specified number `N` of resamples is returned in an array, one column per resample.

```R
sample.boot <- function(N=1, x) {
  n <- length(x)
  samples <- combn(2*n-1, n-1)                         # Columns represent possible bootstrap samples
  counts <- apply(rbind(0, samples, 2*n), 2, diff) - 1 # Counts the stars between the bars
  p <- exp(-colSums(lfactorial(counts)))               # Relative chances of the samples
  p <- p / sum(p)
  j <- sample.int(ncol(samples), N, replace=TRUE, prob=p)
  apply(counts[, j, drop=FALSE], 2, function(i) rep(x, i))  # Replicates each `x[i]` `n.i[i]` times
}
```

*E.g.*, the commands

```R
X <- sample.boot(1e5, c("a", "b", "c"))
table(apply(X, 2, paste0, collapse=""))
```

produce the output

> ```
>   aaa   aab   aac   abb   abc   acc   bbb   bbc   bcc   ccc 
>  3655 11171 11127 11031 22145 11224  3725 11148 11105  3669
> ```

The first line is the ordered bootstrap resample and beneath it are the counts of how many times each resample appeared among $10^5$ draws.  For instance, the chances of `aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc` are all $1/3^3,$ for expected frequencies of $10^5/3^3 \approx 3704.$  The actual frequencies in this experiment were $3655,$ $3725,$ and $3669,$ differing from their expectations by small amounts attributable to the randomness of the drawing.

---

#### References

1. Richard Stanley, *Enumerative Combinatorics* (Volume I), Second Edition.  Available at [http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/ec/).
2. Almost any resource on mathematical problem solving at an elementary level ("elementary" does not mean "easy" or "unsophisticated"!).  See https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/ for instance.

Comment: If I understand things correctly, your sample.boot function will produce bootstrap samples that have a different distribution than straight i.i.d. sampling from the empirical distribution, because the latter produces a uniform distribution of ordered samples, whereas yours produces a uniform distribution over distinct samples ignoring the order. Not sure how much of a problem that is and what implications it has?

Comment: @Christian To what problem are you referring?  The distinction between sampling with and without replacement from the bootstrap distribution, perhaps?

Comment: According to Efron's original paper (and probably most literature), standard nonparametric bootstrap is defined as i.i.d. sampling from the empirical distribution. Are you claiming that your sample.boot function produces the same distribution over bootstrap samples than that? I doubt it.

Comment: Example $N=4$. Probability under i.i.d. sampling to obtain four times the first sample element is $(1/4)^4$. What you do seems to produce a uniform distribution over the possible distinct bootstrap samples. There are, if I'm not mistaken, 35 of these, so the probability for the bootstrap sample above under your scheme will be 1/35, which is different. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Christian You are absolutely right.  I am grateful for your attention to this (and wish the system allowed me to award you reputation for your efforts).  I have fixed the example so it generates bootstrap resamples with the correct probabilities.